# Switch from NSURLConnection to NSURLSession in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I have this code in Objective-C which works with the `initWithRequest` of `NSURLConnection` class and Xcode gives me the following warning:

> initWithRequest is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS9 - Use NSURLSession

My `ViewController.m` code is as follows:

```
NSString url = "my url"; 
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
conexion = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

`Conexion` is `NSURLConnection` in `ViewController.h`, so i was wondering how to switch from `NSURLConnection` to `NSURLSession`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to continue to use delegate-based API, like your current implementation, it's:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:URL];
[task resume];
```

If you do that, you have to conform to [`NSURLSessionDelegate`](http://URL%20Session%20Programming%20Guide), [`NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLSessionTaskDelegate), [`NSURLSessionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLSessionDataDelegate) methods, much like your current `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods.

By the way, I show `dataTaskWithURL` above, but if you really need to use `NSURLRequest` (e.g. you're going to do POST or other request), there is `dataTaskWithRequest`, too.

Having said that, using the completion handler rendition is much easier, saving you have having to write all of those delegate methods:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

NSURLSessionTask *task = [session dataTaskWithURL:URL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // process response here
}];
[task resume];
```

If you do this, you don't have to implement any of those delegate methods. It's analogous to the `NSURLConnection` convenience method `sendAsynchronousRequest`, except it is cancellable.

And, just like the above `dataTaskWithURL`, there are also download and upload specific renditions, `downloadTaskWithURL` and `uploadTaskWithRequest`.

For more information, see [Using NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1) in the *URL Session Programming Guide.*

Comment: Cool! BTW: How would you handle multiple requests? Wouldn't be better to use a NSOperationQueue?

Comment: If using the `delegate` approach, the same delegate methods will be called for all of the requests. But when you create the requests, each is assigned a unique `taskIdentifier` and you can reference that, or refer to the `URL` of the `originalRequest` property of the `NSURLSessionTask`. Or you can associate a `taskDescription`, too. But if you use the `completionHandler` approach it's even easier, because each completion closure is associated with its respective request/URL.

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                  // ...
                              }];

[task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to ask is whether you want to change APIs or not.  NSURLSession is available only in iOS 7 and later, and in OS X v10.9 and later.  If you need to support anything prior to that, you have to either use different code on different OS versions or stick with NSURLConnection.

Given how broadly NSURLConnection is deployed, it is probably safe to say that it won't ever go away—so much so that even when Apple had the opportunity to make a clean break with tvOS, they chose to keep it around.

So to be brutally honest, unless you have some particular reason to use the new features in NSURLSession, the best course is probably to use pragmas to silence the compiler warning for that bit of code, and to use NSURLSession for new code going forwards (assuming you don't need to be compatible with older OSes that don't support NSURLSession).